# Play audio when TextView is touched

Tags: android, android-layout

I want audio to be played when I select/touch a particular TextView. The problem I'm facing is I need to touch the text 3 times to get it to play.

When the activity launches, the first TexTView starts to scroll automatically, whereas the second scrolls only when it is first clicked. I want BOTH TextViews to scroll only when clicked and the audio to start playing on the FIRST click itself.

Here's the extract from the layuot file

```
                             <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/text1"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="1"
                                android:focusable="true"
                                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:text="@string/text1"
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:textSize="30dp" />

                             <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/text2"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:ellipsize="marquee"
                                android:marqueeRepeatLimit="1"
                                android:focusable="true"
                                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:text="@string/text2"
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:textSize="30dp" />
```

Java file

```
text1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mediaPlayer1 != null && mediaPlayer1.isPlaying()) {
            text1.setClickable(false);
        }



        if (mediaPlayer1 == null) {
            mediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.audio1);
        }

        else {
            text1.setClickable(true);
            mediaPlayer1.start();
            play1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            pause1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            repeatoff1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            stop1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
```

Comment: I believe it should be played when clicked twice.

Comment: Sometimes happens when clicked twice, but mostly it happens when clicked thrice, isn't there a way to get it done in one click?

Answer (score 0):

On your first click, you are only initialising `MediaPlayer` and not using it further. Try the following code:

```
text1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mediaPlayer1 != null && mediaPlayer1.isPlaying()) { 
            text1.setClickable(false); 

            // release the media player
            mediaPlayer1.release;
            mediaPlayer1 = null;
        } 



        if (mediaPlayer1 == null) { 
            mediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.audio1);
        } 
        // no need of else
            text1.setClickable(true); 
            mediaPlayer1.start(); 
            play1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            pause1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            repeatoff1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            stop1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```